# How to deny access to directory for all file extensions except few

Tags: nginx

The same as in the title, I want to deny access for all file extensions except these 8. I have got something like this, but it does not work properly.

```
    location ~* /uploads/ql/icons/.*.(?!(bmp|gif|tiff|jpeg|jpg|ppm|png|ico))$ {
       deny all;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex won't work as you expected.
Try this one:

```
location ~* /uploads/ql/icons/.*\.(?!bmp$|gif$|tiff$|jpeg$|jpg$|ppm$|png$|ico$) {
    deny all;
}
```

However this one won't block access to files without any extension at all. To block that files too you'll need a more complex regex:

```
location ~* /uploads/ql/icons/(?:[^.]+$|.*\.(?!bmp$|gif$|tiff$|jpeg$|jpg$|ppm$|png$|ico$)) {
    deny all;
}
```

There is also another way adding second `location` block, see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1039259/nginx-deny-everything-matching-a-pattern-with-one-exception/1039263#comment1352816_1039259) comment.

Comment: It does not work as expected too, I am still able to fetch resources with all file extensions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the `~*` modifier. Fixed an answer. Did you try these regexes with or without it?